# FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder, Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0

Im having a WebApplication that runs in vs2010 but the target framework is set as 2.0. The application uses enterprise library. when I execute the application in my local I getting an error

> Required permissions cannot be acquired.
>   Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Required
>   permissions cannot be acquired.

and in the stack trace I'm getting error

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder, Version=1.0.51205.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

If is set the target framework as 4.0 the code executes fine. I have tried the following steps :

> 1. set the 'Copy to output directory' in the objectbuilder dll property as
>      copy always (earlier it was do not copy)
> 2. tried adding the trust tag with 
>      trust level="high" originUrl=""  and also trust level="low"
>      originUrl=""

copied the below tags from the machine.config of 4.0 to machine.config of 2.0

> section name="fullTrustAssemblies"
>   type="System.Web.Configuration.FullTrustAssembliesSection, System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
>
> section name="partialTrustVisibleAssemblies"
>   type="System.Web.Configuration.PartialTrustVisibleAssembliesSection,
>   System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

but still getting the error. Please let me know what could be the issue..

Comment: Check if the version specified on web.config is the same of EL dll, try to install the EL assembly on GAC

Comment: Hi.. prob solved.. i took the EL dlls seperately, gave it strong name & registered the assembly in GAC.. and now the code works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prob solved.. i took the EL dlls seperately, gave it strong name & registered the assembly in GAC.. and now the code works fine..